# How to install gazebo from source in ROS groovy?

Tags: gazebo, groovy

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

I noticed after installing ROS Groovy that it still comes with the old Fuerte version of Gazebo 1.0.2 ( is this normal? ) which is buggy.

Is there any tutorial how to install from source a new stable version of Gazebo in ROS Groovy?

Thanks,
Andrei

EDIT: My system had more Gazebo versions installed which caused conflicts, I had to remove all ROS and GAZEBO components and make a fresh install of Gazebo and ROS binary versions.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/260/how-to-install-gazebo-from-source-in-ros-groovy?/) by [AndreiHaidu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/87/andreihaidu/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 2108 on 2012-11-21

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bit-pirate](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/143/bit-pirate/) on 2013-01-13**:
I have version 1.2.5 in Groovy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

look at this question in [ros.answers](http://answers.ros.org/question/49397/how-to-install-gazebo-from-source-in-ros-fuerte/?comment=49413#comment-49413)

---

Originally posted by [joseescobar60](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/105/joseescobar60/) with karma: 36 on 2012-11-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [asomerville](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/65/asomerville/) on 2012-11-30**:
@joseescobar60 looks like you just got above 16 karma which means you can now vote. Can you look around and find things worth up-voting. We have a karma credit crunch at the moment which is preventing the community participation bootstrap process.

**Comment by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) on 2013-01-13**:
I just changed the upvote limit to 0 karma.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Last release of [simulator_gazebo 1.7.6 in groovy](http://ros.org/wiki/simulator_gazebo/ChangeList/1.7#A1.7.6_.282012-11-21.29) should have been based on gazebo 1.2, not 1.0.2.

By the way, just released simulator_gazebo 1.7.7, [see ChangeList](http://ros.org/wiki/simulator_gazebo/ChangeList/1.7#A1.7.7_.282013-01-13.29) for updates.
The groovy deb build status can be found [here](http://www.ros.org/debbuild/groovy.html).

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6/hsu/) with karma: 1873 on 2013-01-14

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1